# python decorator adds function to list on object

Tags: python, python-decorators

In python I need to make a list of properties on my class which I may serialise, it is cumbersome to list these at the top of the class. Instead I would like to use a decorator in the same way @property is used, ie something like this:

```
class MyClass(object):

    # I dont like having to do this for example
    #__list_of_props_to_serialise__ = ['my_prop',]

    @property
    @serialise
    def my_prop(self):
        return "this is my property"

    def serialise(self):
        return {f: self.getattr(f) for f in self.__list_of_props_to_serialise__}
```

where `__list_of_props_to_serialise__` is updated on the object by the decorator when the class is built so I dont need the commented out lines at the start.

The problem is when I come to write the decorator I don't have access to the class or object until I actually call the `my_prop` function so I cannot add it. Am I 'doing it wrong', Is there a better way to do this, or can this be done somehow?

If this can be done can some please show a decorator function I can use, else if there is a better way please give an example.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of building up a list, just add a tagging attribute to the function object. Then enumerate all functions on the class that have that attribute.

Because you have *`property`* objects here, you can only find that attribute on the getter of the property object, so you need to make sure that you access the property on the type and not the instance, and then trigger the getter separately:

```
def serialise(func):
    func._do_serialise = True
    return func

def serialisables(obj):
    cls = type(obj)
    cls_attrs = ((name, getattr(cls, name, None)) for name in dir(obj))
    return {name: getattr(obj, name) for name, attr in cls_attrs
            if isinstance(attr, property) and getattr(attr.fget, '_do_serialise', False)}
```

Demo:

```
>>> def serialise(func):
...     func._do_serialise = True
...     return func
...
>>> def serialisables(obj):
...     cls = type(obj)
...     cls_attrs = ((name, getattr(cls, name, None)) for name in dir(obj))
...     return {name: getattr(obj, name) for name, attr in cls_attrs
...             if isinstance(attr, property) and getattr(attr.fget, '_do_serialise', False)}
...
>>> class MyClass(object):
...     @property
...     @serialise
...     def my_prop(self):
...         return "this is my property"
...
>>> serialisables(MyClass())
{'my_prop': 'this is my property'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write your decorator outside the class, with an argument "self" corresponding to the MyClass type object :

```
def serialise(func):
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if func.__name__ not in self.serialisables:
            self.serialisables.append(func.__name__)
            print("Adding " + func.__name__)
        return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

Then initialize your list of serialisables in MyClass:

```
class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.serialisables = []

    @property
    @serialise
    def my_prop(self):
        return "this is my property"
```

When you use the property, its name will be added to the serialisables attribute:

```
>>> c = MyClass()
>>> c.my_prop
Adding my_prop
this is my property
>>> c.serialisables
['my_prop']
```

However, the name of the property will only be added when c.my_prop is used:

```
>>> c = MyClass()
>>> c.serialisables
[]
```

Comment: This is exactly where I was, and exactly what I was trying to avoid I am afraid.

Comment: @othane I'm sorry I misunderstood. I thought the problematic was "I don't have access to the class or object", which the call to "self" solved. After reading again I can see it was not the case.